# What are the limits to meeting your self in the past?

Tags: dc, time-travel, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In DC's Legends of Tomorrow, it was said in one of the episodes (I can't remember or find the correct episode) by Rip that making contact with your younger self can jeopardize your entire existence. In more episodes, (also unknown) Professor Stein meets his younger self, and even tells him that they are the same people. In another episode, Sara talks to her younger self. Eventually, Mick and Ray even meet their younger selves. What are the boundaries to meeting your younger self that prevents their existence from being corrupt? Why are they somehow able to do it when it was said to be a rule not to?

Comment: I hope one of them was Douglas Adams' rule "Never call yourself on the phone when in the past."

Comment: We can only hope for now...

Comment: I'm mostly familiar with the Flash TV series. Using that as a background for how time travel had been handled in that universe. I think it's most safe to say (and almost a cop-out w/o examples) that how much a person affects time travel by interacting with them self is more dependent on how that individual would act with the knowledge that is imparted on them. Depending on the specific information or it's relevance would certainly change the gravity of the experience. What would you do if a future you told you, your dog will die vs. don't ride that bus tomorrow (you never ride buses anyway?)